# Finding Prime Number: error: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++, boolean, primes

I was coding to find the prime number and extract the result as a boolean (true/false or 1/0) using the below code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrimeNumber(int n) {
    int m, i;
    m = n / 2;
    for (i = 2; i < m; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    cout << isPrimeNumber(33);
    return 0;
}
```

(Here the result should be 0 since 67 is a prime number)

(I'm skipping negative numbers and 0,1, but I will add it later)

Then on line 9, it said "error: control reaches end of non-void function."

I tried to find the solution on the Internet, and of course, StackOverflow. But my code was still right and buildable.

I think it has something to do with treating warnings as errors (I changed it under recommendation as a beginner). But I don't wanna change it back since I'm still learning.

Do you have a way to solve this problem without changing my setup back to normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When n is odd you get the error :

> error: control reaches end of non-void function.

You're checking divisibility of **n by only one value i=2**. You have to check for each value of i from 2 to m.

Return **false** after iteration of for loop is completed.
Change your `isPrimeNumber()` function as below:-

```cpp
bool isPrimeNumber(int n){
int m,i;
m = n/2;
    for (i=2;i<m;i++){
      if (n % i == 0){
         return true;
      }
    }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it clearer? I know this fixed my problem but how? You can not-use ELSE in an IF statement too?

Comment: Your code checks divisibility of n by only one number that is 2 you have to check for every value of i. If it is not divisible by 2 your code returns false.

Comment: To add as a bit of clarification: the reason why you got the compiler error was that in case of `m <= i`, your original loop would not run at all and your function would end without returning anything. The compiler expected the function to return a `bool`, but found a case where this is not true, and therefore complained.

Comment: Yes when n is odd it would not return bool and gives the error.